# Estilização de Option via CSS

Tags: css, html-option

fiz alguns `Select` e dentro deles há `Options`.
Tentei estilizar o Option, só que não estou conseguindo, estou fazendo algo errado?

HTML:

```
<div class="imobSelect">
 <select>
  <option>Todos</option>
  <option>teste1</option>
  <option>teste2</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imobSelect select {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: transparent;
width: 233px;
color: #474747;
padding: 8px 5px 5px 5px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1;
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
height: 34px;
-webkit-appearance: none;}

.imobSelect option {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-top: 12px;}

.imobSelect {
    width: 207px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3px;}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: O que está faltando?

Comment: Se você acessar aqui www.felipestoker.com/imob verá que os Options não são estilizados no Chrome. E que no Mozilla, ele fica com uma borda preta ao redor.

Comment: O que está acontecendo de errado?

Comment: Poderia esclarecer qual é a sua dúvida? Está difícil de entender o que vc precisa.

Comment: Qual era exatamente o objetivo com esses estilos? Qual parte não ficou como você gostaria? Qual a dúvida? Mais detalhes ajudariam a esclarecer.

Comment: Já encontrei o que precisava. Estilizar Options é chato demais, cada navegador trata ele com particularidades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options são realmente um dos piores elementos de se estilizar. O suporte dado pelos navegadores varia muito. Eu não recomendaria tentar estilizar esses elementos se você quer consistência do visual entre navegadores.

- **Chrome:** aceita `color`, `background-color` e mais nada que eu testei
- **IE8:** aceita somente `color` e `background-color`, mas além disso, quando um dos options está selecionado, o texto do select fica igual ao do option
- **Firefox:** aceita todos os estilos que eu testei

### Solução javascript

Se uma solução javascript for aceitável, eu recomendaria o **[chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**. Ele substitui o select por `ul` e `li`s, que podem ser estilizados. Este plugin depende do jQuery, então talvez não seja uma opção para o seu caso.

Comment: Verdade, estava analisando as tags de forms, e realmente é muito chato estilizar sem usar Javascript. Vou ter que analisar algum plugin e usá-lo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Alterei a linha de bakcground ( removi a cor de fundo e funcionou normalmente )

```
background: url(../img/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right;
```

Verifique se era esse o problema.

Comment: É boa prática a quem dá voto negativo explicar porquê. Somos uma comunidade e assim aprendêmos mais uns com os outros.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que você tentar estilizar um option você não irá estilizá-lo, apenas algumas atribuições dadas aos selects, serão também atribuidas aos options. Por Exemplo

```
select{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #f2f2f3;
    padding-left: 100px
}
```

No caso do text-align: center isso não funciona, para alinhar basta usar o padding-left. E nos options ele receberam a formatação do select porém ficarão com o seu tamanho e outros requisitos padronizados pelo navegador.

E se você quiser estilizar aquela setinha dos selects. [Aqui](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/#.UGWhd03A_TA) existe um exemplo em jquery